# Asp.net Razor Page for Edit Article don't get affected after doing the Edit just return the same Article

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

Hi trying to edit an article of a Razor page and the application return to the same page and don't do anything to the article, my methods are pretty correct i guess the problem is only in my Edit.cshtml.cs code

here is the code for the page

```
        public OperationResult Edit(EditArticle command)
    {
        var operation = new OperationResult();
        var article = _articleRepository.GetWithCategory(command.Id);

        if (article == null)
            return operation.Failed(ApplicationMessages.RecordNotFound);

        if (_articleRepository.Exists(x => x.Title == command.Title && x.Id != command.Id))
            return operation.Failed(ApplicationMessages.DuplicatedRecord);

        var slug = command.Slug.Slugify();
        var path = $"{article.Category.Slug}/{slug}";
        var pictureName = _fileUploader.Upload(command.Picture, path);
        var publishDate = command.PublishDate.ToGeorgianDateTime();

        article.Edit(command.Title, command.ShortDescription, command.Description, pictureName,
            command.PictureAlt, command.PictureTitle, publishDate, slug, command.Keywords, command.MetaDescription,
            command.CanonicalAddress, command.CategoryId);

        _articleRepository.SaveChanges();
        return operation.Succeded();
    }

    public EditArticle GetDetails(long id)
    {
        return _articleRepository.GetDetails(id);
    }
```

I guess the issue is here down below

```
public IActionResult OnPost(EditArticle command)
    {
        var result = _articleApplication.Edit(command);
        
        return RedirectToPage("./Index",result);
    }
```

Comment: Have you used the debugger to see what goes on?

Comment: No I didn't I will do and update

Answer (score 0):

I agree with your guess...

Firstly, here's the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/da1?view=aspnetcore-6.0#review-concurrency-exception-handling) which showed us 2 kinds of redirection, `return NotFound();` or `return RedirectToPage("./Index");`. I test it in my side and it worked well.

Then let's come back to `RedirectToPage` method, it only provides these kind of constructor, there isn't a method which supporting `RedirectToPage(string pageName, OperationResult opr)`, and you also don't show what is your `OperationResult`.

[image]

In my opinion, you may replace your `OperationResult` with string like `"NotFound", "Duplicated", "Success"`, and you can validate the result string in `OnPost` method to decide how to redirect result.